# Pass a list of string to a declared class file

Tags: java

Hi All below is my Employeeinformation class file java. I have to pass the values to it through java code 
I am fine passing the strings but i am unable to pass list of technologies and list of strings.

**Technologies.java**

```
package com.ElasticSearchCrud.ElasticSearchCrud;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Technologies {

    private String name;
    private  String yearsOfExperience;

}
```

**Employeeinformation.java**

```
package com.ElasticSearchCrud.ElasticSearchCrud;

import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class EmployeeInformation {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Technologies> technologies;
    private List<String> emails;


    public EmployeeInformation(String id, String firstName, String lastName, List<Technologies> technologies, List<String> emails) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.technologies = technologies;
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public List<Technologies> getTechnologies() {
        return technologies;
    }

    public void setTechnologies(List<Technologies> technologies) {
        this.technologies = technologies;
    }

    public List<String> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }

    public void setEmails(List<String> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }
}
```

**Passing a value to class file**

```
EmployeeInformation EmployeePost = new EmployeeInformation("3", "Vignesh", "Murali","?","?");
```

How to pass the list of technologies and list of string in above code. Could some one help me tho achieve this?

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question? You ask how to pass to your `EmployeeInformation` but then you provide an example of just that... also, it should be `EmployeeInformation employeePost` or something like that because classes start with an uppercase, objects should start with lowercase.

Comment: Create the arraylist of technology and arraylist of strings and pass...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Technologies> technologies = new ArrayList<>();
    technologies.add(new Technologies("name1", "1999"));
    technologies.add(new Technologies("name2", "1999"));

    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    strs.add("one");
    strs.add("two");

    EmployeeInformation EmployeePost = new EmployeeInformation("3", "Vignesh", "Murali",technologies,emails);
```

Also add @AllArgsConstructor to Technologies class. Or use setters to init Technologies objects:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Technologies {

    private String name;
    private  String yearsOfExperience;

}
```

Comment: with out adding this only i got error @AllArgsConstructor

Comment: now it's fine it has almost taken my 2 hrs thanks a lot

Comment: @Data creates constructor with parameters (name, yearsOf..) only if fields have final modificator (private final String name). It is a good practice to make all fields final (if it is possible) Use final or #AllArgs.. . Or set field parameters via setters.  But it is inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

@Data annotation has inner @RequiredArgsConstructor. This constructor is created with all non-initialized FINAL properties.
If you have not final properties there will be empty constructor. 
So you have 3 ways:

1. Set you fields as final: `new SomeObject(List.of("1","2"));`
2. Add @AllArgsConstuctor: result the same
3. Leave as it is and initialize an object by set methods

   SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
   obj.setList(List.of("1", "2"));